# jquery .$ajax content loads only after refresh(F5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

On an external server there is a folder consisting with some .html files, one of them is the index.html.

Server can load both: foldername or foldername/index.html in his url.
In every html file I load a js file. 
Now the problem is, that the remote json file from my server exists at {filename}.json. 
This concept works fine but when I first load only the foldername without index.html, the index.json file seems not to be used.

After refreshing the page (F5) or open the page for the first time with activated developer tool to see the console.log it works as it should.
This is tested with google chrome and FF.

Here's the relevant code:

```
//test if url ends with :html
var loc = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var last = loc[loc.length-1] || loc[loc.length-2];

//if not take index.json as file name
if(!last.match(/html/)){
  var file_json = "index.json";
}
else{
  var file_json = last.replace(/html/,"json");
}
var URL = base + "/" + file_json;
$.ajax({
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: false
  },
  type: "GET",
  url: URL
  }).done(function (data) {
  ...
  }
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Do you put your script under $(document).ready ?

Comment: Where is the question here? Your code does exactly what you explained. What do you want to be different?

Comment: @Gavriel than this is the problem. I'm not a jquery / js evangelist! When the code is wrong to load and compute the data immediately, than this is my problem. Wrong code!?

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the above code into a function:

```
function myCode(){
    // all the above code comes here
}
```

and call `myCode();` whenever you want it to run. You probably will want to run it when you click something, for example:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="myCode();"/>
```

Comment: THX for your comment, but Joshua H was right. I took a $document.ready and the phenomenon was away. But thank you anyway!!!